# Do the properties of cauchy sequences carry over to converging functions?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f$ be a function that is increasing and bounded above. Then $f$ is converging. I know that a converging sequence {$x_n$} is Cauchy. So does $f$ take on the definition of a Cauchy sequence too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\xi$ be a limit point of the domain $D$ of $f$. Then $f$ *satisfies the Cauchy condition* for $x\to\xi$ if for any given $\epsilon>0$ there is a neighborhood $U$ of $\xi$ such that
$$|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon\qquad\forall x, \> y\in\dot U\ .$$

If $D\subset{\mathbb R}$ is a finite interval, and $\xi=\sup D$ then the Cauchy condition means that for any $\epsilon>0$ we can find a $\delta>0$ such that
$$|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon\qquad\forall\> x, \>y\in\ ]\xi-\delta, \ \xi[\  .$$
If $D=[a,\infty[\ $ for some $a\in{\mathbb R}$ then the Cauchy condition makes sense for $x\to\infty$, and reads as follows: For any given $\epsilon>0$ there is an $M\geq a$ such that
$$|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon\qquad\forall \>x, \>y>M\ .$$
One has the following

**Theorem:** If $f$ satisfies the Cauchy condition for  $x\to\xi$ then the limit $\lim_{x\to\xi}f(x)$ exists.

Answer (score 0):

The notion of Cauchy sequences is extremely general and can be applied to many, many things. It's no accident that you consider such things in introductory real analysis. That said, your case is not really any different than the case of $\Bbb R$ because you're interested in sequences of values of $f$, which are likely real numbers so Cauchy sequence arguments will work there as well.